# dropdown wont autohides when click on blank space

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make dropdown but dropdown wont autohides when click on blank space from the page. When user clicks on any place other than dropdown menu then i want to hide the list.

how to tackle this situation. Please suggest me

i want to make dropdown but dropdown wont autohides when click on blank space from the page. When user clicks on any place other than dropdown menu then i want to hide the list.

how to tackle this situation. Please suggest me

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #C6C6C6;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 177px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: gray;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Country</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#">Germany</a>
    <a href="#">Switzerland</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click event on the window and check if the click is outside the drop down, then close it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown")
  const parent = myDropdown.parentElement;
  
  myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");

  window.addEventListener("click", closeOutside)

  function closeOutside(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    if(target === parent || parent.contains(target))
      return;
    
    myDropdown.classList.remove("show");
    window.removeEventListener("click", closeOutside)
  }
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #C6C6C6;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 177px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: gray;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Country</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#">Germany</a>
    <a href="#">Switzerland</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an event on the `document` that checks to see if it wasn't the button that was clicked and if so, hide the list.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
 if(event.target !== document.querySelector(".dropbtn")){
   myFunction();
 }
});
```

```css
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #C6C6C6;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 177px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: gray;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Country</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#">Germany</a>
    <a href="#">Switzerland</a>
  </div>
</div>
```